# My phone doesn't vibrate

Tags: java, android

I tried to vibrate on my android phone that Samsung Galaxy3 (android 4.1.2). 
But It's not working. 
I don't know why this problem occured.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.vibration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);        
    vibe.vibrate(2000);

    //LogCat
    if (vibe.hasVibrator()) {
        Log.v("Can Vibrate", "YES");
        vibe.vibrate(6000);
    } else {
        Log.v("Can Vibrate", "NO");
    }


}
```

}

**LogCat Information**  
It's working (I found **YES**).. but my phone doesn't vibrate :-(

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vibration"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category   android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you for in advance

Comment: Have you checked to see if you've disabled vibration in your phone's settings?

Comment: I enabled 'auto haptic' option.
(Settings->Sound->enable Auto haptic)
When I restarted my app, It's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem.

Then I turned on my "Touch on vibration" option from my phone settings(sound settings) and it started working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mistake in your code.

I tried it to be sure and it works fine. 
Are you sure your vibration sensor works?
If there is no defect with your phone I do not understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I enabled 'auto haptic' option.
(Settings->Sound->enable Auto haptic)
When I restarted my app, It's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For my google pixel 1 xl it has to have power from the wall or a from a USB port. It has to be in a charging state also make sure battery saver is turned off.